# I cannot figure out how to get rid of this math domain error

Tags: python

```
def q(a,b,c):
    discriminate = (b**2) - (4*a*c)

    s1 = (-b+math.sqrt(discriminate))/(2*a)
      
    s2 = (-b-math.sqrt(discriminate))/(2*a)
   
    return (s1,s2)
```

So far I have this written down and it keeps giving me a math domain error that I must resolve without using cmath I cannot seem to figure out what to do

Comment: Can you please include the run of the function that raises this error? What are the inputs to the function `q`?

Comment: s1 = (-b+math.sqrt(discriminate))/(2*a) this line leads to a math domain error because it's taking the square root of a negative I'm supposed to have it this way and it should output a complex number

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 cases that you need to take care of:

- discriminate < 0    **--> no real solution**
- discriminate == 0   **--> 1 real solution**
- discriminate > 0    **--> 2 real solutions**

Add this logic to your code.

Comment: actually, I'm supposed to include imaginary numbers